# Find the minimum value of $a^2 + b^2 + 5 - ab - 2a - 2b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, contest-math

> Find the minimum value (integer) of $a^2 + b^2 + 5 - ab - 2a - 2b$.

I believe the answer is $1$, I got this from trial-and-error.

$= a^2 + b^2 - ab - 2(a + b) + 5 = (a + b)^2 - 2(a+ b) - 3ab + 5$

$=(a + b)(a + b - 2) - 3ab + 5$.

Doesnt work.

$=(a - b)^2 + ab + -2(a + b) + 5$.

Doesnt work either.

$a^2 + b^2 + 5 - ab - 2a - 2b \ge 6\sqrt[6]{-20a^4b^4}$

But that will lead to the imaginary realm. (Is there a way using AM-GM?)

**Is there an algebraic solution?**

Answer (score 4):

We have

$$\begin{align}&a^2+b^2+5-ab-2a-2b\\&=a^2+(-b-2)a+b^2-2b+5\\&=\left(a-\frac{b+2}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{b+2}{2}\right)^2+b^2-2b+5\\&=\left(a-\frac{b+2}{2}\right)^2+\frac 34b^2-3b+4\\&=\left(a-\frac{b+2}{2}\right)^2+\frac 34(b-2)^2+1\\&\ge 1\end{align}$$

The equality is attained when $a-\frac{b+2}{2}=b-2=0$, i.e. $a=b=2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$2(a^2+b^2+5-ab-2a-2b)=(a^2-2ab+b^2)+(a^2-4a+4)+(b^2-4b+4)+2=(a-b)^2+(a-2)^2+(b-2)^2+2\ge 2$$,which implies that $a^2+b^2+5-ab-2a-2b\ge 1$.Equality holds for $a=b=2$.

Answer (score 0):

If we replace a with b and b with a the expression doesn't changes. Hence we can conclude that a=b and let a=b=x. substituting in the given expression we get,
$\begin{align}
  & {{a}^{2}}+{{b}^{2}}+5-ab-2a-2b=2{{x}^{2}}+5-{{x}^{2}}-4x \\ 
 & ={{x}^{2}}-4x+5 \\ 
 & ={{\left( x-2 \right)}^{2}}+1 \\ 
\end{align}$

Or the minimium value will be 1 at x=2.